# Setting bitrate of video in FFmpeg

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, h.264, codec

I use FFmpeg to record videos from a RTSP stream (the codec is H.264). It works. But I face a problem with the bitrate value. First, I set bitrate like below, but it doesn't work:

```
AVCodecContext *m_c;
m_c->bit_rate = bitrate_value;
```

[Following this question](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2417) I can set bitrate manually with this command:

```
av_opt_set(m_c->priv_data, "crf", "39", AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
```

But I have to test several times to choose value '39', which creates acceptable video quality. It's hard to do it again if I use another camera setting (image width, height, etc). Is there a way to set bitrate more easily, and adaptively?

Comment: Don't bother `crf` and choose a preset. As far as I know, ffmpeg h264 encoding doesn't have a native constant bit rate mode.

Comment: Could you help me with an example how to choose a preset? Thanks

Comment: @halfelf `-x264opts nal-hrd=cbr`

Comment: @aergistal `nal-hrd` is not recommended for normal videos. Also this option needs other ffmpeg option to simulate cbr.

Comment: @halfelf That was FYI. With a single-frame VBV it works pretty well if you need to do broadcast.